# Html button edit table

Tags: html, button, html-table

I'm looking to create a table in HTML like in this link : https://unbelievaboat.com/commands.

I tried to look for something like this, that there is buttons in the side that change the table (with categories).

My code now is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table style="font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;">
  <tr>
    <th>Command</th>
    <th>Info</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Invites</td>
    <td>Bla bla bla</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Util</td>
    <td>Bla bla bla</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Activity</td>
    <td>Bla bla bla</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Admin</td>
    <td>Bla bla bla</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Giveaways</td>
    <td>Bla bla bla</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You probably needs tabs. See this W3 article: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_tabulators.asp

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to use Javascript to do this. What I would do is give the elements in groups classes representing the group. when someone would click a button representing a group, I would hide all the other classes and display the desired class.